# Meaning of はなちゃああああああ in internet slang

Tags: internet-slang

I upload videos on niconico and sometimes I get

> はなちゃああああああ

commented on my videos. I did tons of googling but I got nothing.

Comment: 「はなちゃん」って女の子がいる？

Comment: can you link us to one of those videos? Maybe they're referring to something in them..

Comment: @strawberryjam It's this one: http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm27882096

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it! The mascot character of [Vocaloid V Flower](http://www.v-flower.jp/) is called `[花]{はな}ちゃん` because "flower" is 花 in Japanese. He/she just cried the nickname. It's not Internet slang.